# Set first element in select list as guid empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, guid

I have a dropdownlist as below:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NewPipelineEaPersonId, new SelectList(Model.EaList, "PersonId", "FullName"), "Please select one", new { style = "width: 250px;" })
```

I have my class as follows:-

```
public class LeadPipelineEntry
{
    [Required]
    public int PipelineTransactionId { get; set; }

    public Guid NewPipelineEaPersonId { get; set; }
}
```

The Guid is not required in this part but still it is throwing a required field error.

Also I dont want to make guid as nullable parameter

I know that select field do these.

But can I make the value of 1st Item "Please select one" as `Guid.Empty`?

I want to manage this in the view only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot set the default element of a dropdown list to anything else than an empty string. This simply isn't supported by the DropDownListFor helper. At that's how it should be. You should make the Guid nullable on your view model if you want to allow empty values inside the dropdown.

If you cannot make the Guid nullable on the view model it makes absolutely no sense to provide a default option (`"Please select one"`) for the dropdown list.

You could write a custom DropDownList helper which will provide some default value other than an empty string or generate the select manually - both equally wrong approaches.